# Endpoint which accepts a HttpPostedFileBase and writes the incoming stream to a Webclient for upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, file-upload, stream

I have a endpoint which accepts an HttpPostedFileBase, which provides an input stream which can be read to download the file. I don't actually want to read it - I want to re-post it immediately to another endpoint on a different domain (this is because my API is built on top of another).

Can I do this without waiting for the whole stream to be read? I don't want users of my endpoint to be delayed unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase image)
    string url = "www.example.com";

    using (var wb = new WebClient())
    {
        var stream = wb.OpenWrite(url, "POST");
        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
        while ((read = image.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) 
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately using OpenWrite doesn't really seem to provide any easy option to read the response, so I'll probably just buffer the entire stream and use UploadData :(.

Comment: i'm trying to upload a jpeg file to a server using webclient and httpostedfilebase but webclient is not able to find the path of the httpostedfilebase, do you have an idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431493/how-to-upload-a-file-on-a-server-through-api-call-in-asp-net-mvc