# How to upload a file on a server through api call in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

[image]

```
public ActionResult Index(PublishPost post, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var apiURL = "http://test.sa.com/rest/social/update/1161/upload?access_token=6fWV564kj3drlu7rATh8="
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    byte[] responseBinary = webClient.UploadFile(apiUrl, file.FileName);
    string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBinary);
    /* Giving error here. How to proceed?
}
```

I want to upload a single file to this url and the response is shown in the figure above. How to proceed further with the same in C#? Please help

Comment: Try using fiddler to take a peak at the communications between your client and the server. Might give a hint as to what is breaking (for instance, problems in the way the data is being sent, or http error codes will be easier to interpret in fiddler than trying to debug this). Please post the results.

Comment: Easy way to upload a file using api call is Convert your File into base64 string  and  send string on server then  on server side Convert base64 string to file and store in directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try your code like below.

```
public ActionResult Index(PublishPost post, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var apiURL = "http://test.sa.com/rest/social/update/1161/upload?access_token=6fWV564kj3drlu7rATh8="
    
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.InputStream.Length + 1];                         
            file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = file.FileName };
            content.Add(fileContent);
            var result = client.PostAsync(apiURL, content).Result;
            if (result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return new 
                {
                    code = result.StatusCode,
                    message = "Successful",
                    data = new 
                    {
                        success = true,
                        filename = file.FileName
                    }
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return new 
                {
                    code = result.StatusCode,
                    message = "Error"
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```